# GTM Size Budgets - What's an average Google Tag Manager payload size (kB/files/other)?

Tags: tracking, optimization, google-tag-manager

On a landing page I've built, 80% of what the user downloads in terms of kB and even more in terms of number of files comes from GTM. It's an extremely condensed site outside of the GTM implementation, but it has left us with the question of how large a GTM payload can reasonably be. How can we set ourselves a budget? Is there an average size to compare with? Even if the load is async, there are concerns of the user downloading too much useless nonsense and the extra js slowing down mobile devices.